# Hibernate persist parent or child object

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping

I want to add a "Bar"-object to the "bars"-list in a "Foo"-object. So I create the "Bar"-object, set the "foo"-variable to the parent and add the object to the "bars"-list. Now my question: Do I persist the "Foo"- or the "Bar"-object. Both approaches work, if I just add one object. If I add multipe "Bar"-objects to the "Foo"-object, I get the error: "Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)".

So I think the correct way would be, to persist the "Bar"-object. But if I do that -> I can not update my "numberBars"-variable.

Any suggestions, what's the best way to persist the objects and also update the "numberBars"-variable?

```
public Foo {
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Bar> bars;
  int numberBars;

}

public Bar {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn
  private Foo foo;

}
```

Comment: Why have a `numberBars` variable? You can get that any time you want with `bars.size()` or with `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`.

Comment: For performance reason. Look at the stackoverflow startpage. Lot's of questions. If you have to load the comments for every single one, i think thats a big performance impact? Just showing a field is much more efficient